# Find most recent record from "has one through" relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following tables:

- `matrices` - a matrix name and some other metadata.
- `matrix_values` - stores various data points of a 2D matrix as a JSON value column (Postgres).  Also the FK **matrix_id** for a belongs-to association.
- `products` - a `matrix_value` may be joined to a `product` via join table `matrix_value_products`

  - `matrix_values` *MAY* be associated with only one `product`, but are not required to be; in fact, most aren't.  Which is why is used a join table instead of a belongs-to FK relationship to avoid having mostly NULL values in a FK column

ERD looks like

[image]

Each matrix has several `matrix_values` where either **A)** none of them are associated with a `product`, or **B)** all of them are associated with a product (possibly different products).

In scenario **A**, the multiple records are a history of the 2D matrix, where the most recently created record is the current representation.  This scenario is easy for me to find the most recent `matrix_value`.

How can I create a query for scenario **B** in order to find the most recent `matrix_values` record *per product*? For matrix 777 below, I want to return `matrix_values` records **2** (most recent for product *P*) and **4** (most recent for product *Q*).

[image]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  Postgres.  Added tag for it.

Comment: Answered many, many times: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgreatest-n-per-group%5D+%5Bpostgresql%5D+distinct+on

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  Thanks, I didn't know there was a name for it (*greatest n per group*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT finalValues.* FROM
matrix_values AS finalValues
INNER JOIN matrix_value_products AS finalProducts 
ON finalProducts.matrix_value_id = finalValues.id
AND finalValues.created_at = (
    SELECT max(created_at) 
    FROM matrix_values 
    INNER JOIN matrix_value_products
    ON matrix_values.id = matrix_value_products.matrix_value_id
    WHERE matrix_value_products.product_id = finalProducts.product_id
)   
WHERE
        matrix_id = 777
```

In essence you join the two tables and restrict them to the Matrix values of the appropriate Matrix. Then you Limit the whole Thing by a subquery that only Returns the most recent (thus max as I take it that created_at is a datetime(2) field) entry. You have to use the same inner join as only so you can Limit it to the products associated with the Matrix values you want to finally get.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't stated any *DBMS* so, i would use `subquery` which is ANSI SQL.

```
select p.*, mv.*
from matrix_value_products mvp inner join 
     products p
     on p.id = mvp.product_id inner join
     matrix_values mv
     on mv.id = mvp.matrix_value_id
where mv.id = (select max(mvp1.matrix_value_id)
               from matrix_value_products mvp1
               where mvp1.product_id = mvp.product_id
               );
```

Comment: This does not work.  There is no use of *max(created_at)*.  I see a *max(mvp1.matrix_value_id)*, but that's not what I need.